# Testing HTML in Classic ASP using Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have some problems running an old web application made in Classic ASP.
I'm using Visual Studio Code, but I cannot debug the HTML code.
For example, I have some errors in the:

X-Powered-by

But I can't find any HTML file containing the Body, that is the writing in the various paragraphs.
So the first important step for me would be to be able to view the site on the browser when I start Visual Studio Code.
So you can begin to see and understand what happens instantly with each change on the HTML. (Always managing to understand if it is possible to modify the HTML part, since it is an integral or even "hidden" part from the programming files in ASP).

How can I proceed?

Comment: `X-Powered-by` is written by IIS

Comment: `X-Powered-by` is not an error it's a standard HTTP header written out by the IIS server, you can remove it and lots do.

Comment: Great, thank you all.